# Updating models in has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-many-through

I have two models, Designer and Influence.
They have a "has_many" relationship to eachother :through a join model called Relation.

I want to use a single form to create/update the designer model with information from the influence model. Is it possible to create a relation object through the create/update actions in the designer controller? Or do I need to create a Relations controller?

My current code is as below, and results in a NoMethodError in DesignersController#Update.

**Designer.rb**

```
attr_accessible :name, :relation, :influence
has_many :relations
has_many :influences, :through => relations
```

**Influence.rb**

```
attr_accessible :name, :relation, :designer
has_many :relations
has_many :designers, :through => :relations
```

**Relation.rb**

```
attr_accessible :designer_id, :influence_id
belongs_to :designer
belongs_to :influence
```

**designers/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @designer do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :influence %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :influence, Influence.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

**designers_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @designer = current_designer
  ** Is there a way to create a new relation object here? **
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 general ways to do this.  You can create a Relations object directly or you can create an Influence object using the Designer association, and one will be made automatically:

`Relation.create relation_attributes`

or

`@designer.influences.create influence_attributes` (this creates a new Relation object)

Comment: Thanks @jordanpg. I will opt for the first, as I do not want to create any new influences, but want to just add existing influences to existing and new designers through new relations. For the first example, how to I reference the influence_id from the collection_select input in the designer form? I have added the following to my update method in my designers controller. </br>   Relation.create(designer_id: current_designer.id, influence_id: :influence_id)   </br> Is this incorrect?

Comment: In the `collection_select` statement, you are already referencing the `influence_id`:  `Influence.order(:name), :id, :name`.  If you want to reference an `influence_id` associated with the @designer object, do: `f.object.influences.first`, for example.  Also, don't forget to accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: Hi @jordanpg, I'll accept as soon as I can get this to work. Sorry for the novice questions...  For the first option, what would be the best way to define "relation_attributes"? I have kept all of my files unchanged, except for adding "Relation.create relation_attributes" to the update method in the designers_controller. This give me "undefined local variable or method 'relation_attributes'". Could you please help me understand where and how can I define this?

Comment: `relations_attributes` was just a stand-in for a hash of attributes for the new Relation object.  So, for example, if a Relation has a name and a color:  `Relation.create({name: 'a name', color: 'blue'})`

Comment: Yes, so Relation has only two attributes, designer_id and influence_id. The first would be equal to current_designer (ie. the person that's editing the form), and the second attribute would be the input from the form. That's why I initially tried "Relation.create(designer_id: current_designer.id, influence_id: :influence_id). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see.  `influence_id` is not set to anything in the Designer controller.  Add `:id` to the view: `f.collection_select :influence, :id, Influence.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true` and then access this in the Designer controller with `params[:influence][:id]`.

Comment: Thanks @jordanpg.     Relation.create(designer_id: current_designer.id, influence_id: params[:influence][:id]) results in undefined method '[]'... I need to go now, but will try again later tonight. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Should be OK...  did you add `:id` to the second argument of `collection_select`?

Comment: Figured it out. I had to remove the "f" from "f.collection select." This makes sense to me, as the "f" is a variable for "@designer", not "@influence". Thanks for the help!